# Нарушение доступа для записи | C++

Tags: c++

```
void CreateParameters(char* param, int key){
    ofstream file("data.dat");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(param); i++) {
        param[i] = 'w'; // Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для записи. param было 0x1C3512A.
    }
    file << param;
}
```

Вызываю функцию так:

```
CreateParameters("123", key);
```

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы

Comment: А что вы передаете в функцию?

Comment: Если хотите использовать сырые указатели, то в эту функцию еще следует передавать размер буфера, на который указывает `param`.

Comment: может вы передаете const char*, следовательно туда нельзя записать...

Comment: На пример: CreateParameters("123", key);

Comment: Строковый литерал - константа, запись в него ведет к самым разным неприятностям...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если функция вызывается так:

```
CreateParameters("fff",0);
```

То ошибка при попытке изменения. Лучше string использовать. Преобразование (char *) ==> (string) без проблем работает. И будет можно так вызывать.

Comment: Зачем именно string? Просто нужно создать копию в памяти, которую можно модифицировать

Comment: Затем что стринг прост и эффективен. А возиться с утечкой памяти в с++ не очень хорошо (вообще в с++ можно ПОЛНОСТЬЮ обойтись без указателей)